# Costs and Payment for Runtime Upgrades in Parachains

Tags: runtime-upgrade

I'm currently working with Substrate parachains and have question that I'm hoping to get clarity on:

**Payment for Runtime Upgrade Execution**: In a parachain context, when a runtime upgrade (an extrinsic) is executed, who is responsible for covering the costs on the relay chain? Is this cost borne by the parachain that's executing the upgrade, or is there a different mechanism in place?

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!